# Facing a problem in posting dynamic data. i'm getting static data instead of dynamic

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

here is the code of my react and I also sharing an image of data which is getting after posting dynamic data. I post and hello world from the input field "add new todo task" but i'm getting data practice more to gain more experience. how to get dynamic data?

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import deleteIcon from "./assets/delete.png";
import './App.modules.css';

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api";

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(null);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    getTodos()
  }, []);
const getTodos = () => {
     axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/todos`)
    .then((res) => setTodos(res.data))
    .catch((err) => console.log("Error getting todos", err))
  };

  const handleAddTodo =  () => {
    axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/todo/new`, {title : "Practice more to gain more experience"})
    .then((res) => {
      setTodos([...todos, res.data]);
      setTodo("");
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("Error adding todo", err));
  };


  const handleDeleteTodo = (id) => {
    axios
    .delete(`${BASE_URL}/todo/delete/${id}`)
    .then((res) => 
        setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo._id !== res.data._id))
    )
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };


  const handleTodoClick = (id) => {
    axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/todo/toggleStatus/${id}`)
    .then((res) => getTodos())
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  };

    return (
    <div className="App">
    <div className='todo-input-wrapper'>
      <input 
        className='todo-input-bar'
        value={todo}
        onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
        placeholder='Add a New Todo Task'  />
        <div className='add-button' onClick={handleAddTodo}>
          +
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className='todos-list'>
      {!todos || !todos.length ? (
          <h2 style={{textAlign : "center" }}>No Tasks Yet Found</h2>
        ) : (
          todos.map((todo) => (
            <div className='todo' key={todo._id}>
              <span onClick={() => handleTodoClick(todo._id)}
              className={todo.complete ? "complete" : ""}
              id='todo-title' >
                {todo.title}
              </span>
              <span className='delete'
              onClick={()=> handleDeleteTodo(todo._id)}>
                <img src={deleteIcon} alt='delete' height="20px" width="20px" />
              </span>
            </div>
          ))
        )
      }
    </div>
 </div>
 )
}

export default App;
```

I try to get hello world but i'm getting static data so now i want to get dynamic data instead of static data

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in your `handleAddTodo` function you are hard coding the todo title every time the function is called. Therefore, it saves same title string for every api call.
Refactor the handleAddTodo method by making the title dynamic.
This shall work:

```
const handleAddTodo =  () => {
    axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/todo/new`, {title : todo})
    /*
     *Rest of the code
    */

  };
```